# Dealing with AFNetworking2.0 asynchronous HTTP request

Tags: objective-c, post, asynchronous, ios7, afnetworking-2

I am very new to the concept of asynchronous programming, but I get the general gist of it (things get run in the backround).

The issue I'm having is I have a method which utilizes AFNetworking 2.0 to make an HTTP post request, and it works for the most part.

However, I can't figure out how to get the method to actually return the value received from the response as the method returns and THEN gets the value from the response.

```
-(int) registerUser
{
self.responseValue = 000; //Notice I set this to 000 at start of method

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"Username": @"SomeUsername" };

[manager POST:@"http://XXX/register"
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     NSError *err = nil;

     self.responseValue = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"res"] intValue]; 
     //Note: This^ value returns 99 and NSLogs confirm this
 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
 }];

return self.responseValue; //This will return 000 and never 99!
}
```

Whats the 'proper' way to handle this situation? I've heard whispers of using a 'callback', but I don't really understand how to implement that in this situation.

Any guidance or help would be awesome, cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting variable from the inside of block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919135/getting-variable-from-the-inside-of-block)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `POST` runs asynchronously, as you point out, so you are hitting the `return` line well *before* the `responseValue` property is actually set, because that `success` block runs later. Put breakpoints/`NSLog` statements in there, and you'll see you're hitting the `return` line first.

You generally do not `return` values from an asynchronous methods, but rather you adopt the completion block pattern. For example:

```
- (void)registerUserWithCompletion:(void (^)(int responseValue, NSError *error))completion
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"Username": @"SomeUsername" };

    [manager POST:@"http://XXX/register"
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

         int responseValue = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"res"] intValue];

         if (completion)
             completion(responseValue, nil);
     }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err)
     {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);

          if (completion)
             completion(-1, err); // I don't know what you want to return if it failed, but handle it appropriately
    }];
}
```

And then, you could use it as follows:

```
[self registerUserWithCompletion:^(int responseValue, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%s: registerUserWithCompletion error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
    else
        NSLog(@"%d", responseValue);

    // do whatever you want with that responseValue here, inside the block
}];

// Needless to say, don't try to use the `responseValue` here, because
// `registerUserWithCompletion` runs asynchronously, and you will probably
// hit this line of code well before the above block is executed. Anything
// that is dependent upon the registration must called from within the above
// completion block, not here after the block.
```

Note, I'd suggest you retire that `responseValue` property you had before, because now that you're using completion blocks, you get it passed back to you via that mechanism, rather than relying on class properties.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. 

When I get back home I'll give this a shot - I've done some reading on completion blocks and I think I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this one and use search ;-))

[Getting variable from the inside of block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919135/getting-variable-from-the-inside-of-block/22941099#22941099)

its a lot of duplicates already!

:-)